# getting wrong result when working with dates

Tags: java, sql, date

```
String date1 = jTextField.getText();

String date2 = jTextField2.getText();

// using CDate...
pre=conn.prepareStatement("select * from Table where Date "
    + "between CDate(?) and CDate(?) order by Date");

pre.setString(1, date1); // bind param 1

pre.setString(2, date2); // bind param 2

ResultSet rs=pre.executeQuery();
```

When we take dates from 01/12/2013 to 31/01/2014 it just returns me records up to 31/12/2013.

Another issue is when we take date from 01/01/2014 to 31/12/2014 then it returns me records from all dates of 2013 also.

Please help me to solve this.

Thank you.

My Date column have data type as Text.

Please provide me correct query to find dates records between two string inputted dates.

Comment: What is `CDate` function? What is your table declaration? Let us see some sample data.

Comment: CDate is to convert string date to Date format

Comment: So let us see its body, and what is your DB?

Comment: I am using MS Access DB

Comment: @MessyProgrammer Your question need much improvement. Are you using a JDBC driver to connect to MS Access? Whose driver? Can you provide a link to Access documentation for the data type used to store your date value? And for the Cdate function. If u r storing value in a textual type why are u calling CDATE to create a date value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you use Ms Access database, and your Date column have data type as Text. Looking at your code you want to search records between two dates. So do this:

- Open your database
- Open your table in design view
- Change data type of Date column as Date/Time

CDate() function will return you Date as 05/01/2013.

If you change the data type to Date/Time, then you have to use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to store your date in to database As:

```
SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String date=format.format(yourDate);
```

Now you can store this date to database.

Now your query will work fine.

Comment: @Jugadu-I have change the data type of Date column to Date/Time ,and it works fine. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Your Date column is a datetime not a date.

To compare the values, the dates from the range are cast to datetime, which is zero-hundred hours at the *stsrt* of the date. That's why you're not seeing the last day's rows.

To fix, add one day to the end date and test for *less than* rather than *beteen* which *includes* the ends of the range - ie *less than or equal*. Use *greater than or equal* for the start.

Comment: my Date column is having Text as a datatype

Comment: So what is `CDate` function?

Comment: @Bohemian (a) Did you mean "date" instead of "dare" in your first line? (b) Rather than subtract 1 second, it would be better to test "LESS THAN" the moment of the new day. Depending on the database, the date-time may be stored with a fraction of a second, so there could be values between "23:59:59" and "00:00:00".